# How to split and replace comma and parenthesis?

Tags: java, android, regex

I have the string value

```
String valueData = "{\"x\":10,\"y\":10,\"z\":10}"
```

How to format as `x:10,y:10,z:10`

Please help me with regular expression

Comment: `String valueData = {"x":10,"y":10,"z":10}.` will not compile.

Comment: Is this string or `json`?Use Json Parser to get x,y,z

Comment: This looks like JSON data to me.  Use a JSON parser and make your life easier.

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/ --- This reads like a do-the-work-for-me question. Sorry, StackOverflow is not a work-for-hire service.

Comment: Correct statement: `String valueData = {"x:10", "y:10", "z:10"};`

Comment: @winchester100 change valueData to `"{\"x\":10,\"y\":10,\"z\":10}"` to be safe from down votes :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
String valueData = "{\"x\":10,\"y\":10,\"z\":10}.";
valueData = valueData.replace(".", "");
valueData = valueData.replace("{", "");
valueData = valueData.replace("}", "");
valueData = valueData.replace("\"", "");
System.out.println(valueData);
```

Comment: @winchester100 because of this **`String valueData = {"x":10,"y":10,"z":10}`**

Comment: @winchester100 because before it was edited your question was incomprehensible

Comment: @SerjArdovic : thanks I made change.If possible please upvote.

Comment: @winchester100 It wasn't me, I try to be tolerant and avoid downvoting questions

Answer (score 1):

`String valueData = {"x":10,"y":10,"z":10}.` it not valid String i think its a `JSON`

You can also try this

```
  StringBuilder stringBuilder= new StringBuilder();
    try {
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject("{\"x\":10,\"y\":10,\"z\":10}");
        Iterator<String> iter = json.keys();
        while (iter.hasNext()) {

            String key = iter.next();
            stringBuilder.append(key+ ":");
            stringBuilder.append(json.getString(key)+",");
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Log.e("DATA",stringBuilder.toString());
```

**OUTPUT**

```
com.example.user33.workingtestapp E/DATA: x:10,y:10,z:10,
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use this :

```
String valueData = "{\"x\":10,\"y\":10,\"z\":10}";
String s = valueData
                .substring(1, valueData.length() - 1)
                .replaceAll("(\\\")(\\w+)(\\\")", "$2");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this :

```
    valueData = valueData.replaceAll("[{\"}\\.]+", "");
    System.out.println(valueData);//x:10,y:10,z:10
```